# Angularjs function call globally

Tags: angularjs

This is my custom controller i written **`logout()`** function here it working fine

my problem is i want to use in this my global menu page

how to achive this ?

**TodoController.js**

```
app.controller('TodoController',  function($state,$http,$rootScope, $scope,$auth) {
    $scope.logout = function() {
        $auth.logout().then(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $rootScope.currentUser = null;
        });
    }

    $scope.init();

});
```

**menu.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/#/url">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/url3">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/url2">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/url1">Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `MenuController` in the same way you created your `TodoController`, and add a `logout()` method there. Make sure to set the `MenuController` on your menu's HTML so that it has access to the method.

Comment: Yes I follewed that also but not calling

Comment: Did you add a click handler on your menu item..? `ng-click="logout()"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Either you can create another controller for it, or make that function global 
 through application and use where ever you want with $rootScope:
$rootScope.logout = function() {
        $auth.logout().then(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $rootScope.currentUser = null;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define your logout function in your main 'app' module's run block. The run block is kind of like an AngularJs main method. In the run block you can attach your logout function to `$rootScope` as mentioned in @Bimlendu Kumar's answer.

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [])
        .run(['$auth', '$rootScope', '$window'
            function($auth, $rootScope, $window) {
                $rootScope.logout = function() {
                    $auth.logout().then(function() {
                        $window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
                        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                        $rootScope.currentUser = null;
                    });
                }
            }
```

Then inside menu.html you just add the function call in the ng-click attribute.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/#/url">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/url3">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/url2">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/url1">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

For more info on run blocks: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module